# Could I prove this result in probability theory when the random variables are defined in fields/groups or abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, abelian-groups

Suppose that $l$, $y$ and $x$ are three different random variables that are uniformly distributed. Say that $l$ is defined over a finite field (or a group) $G$, $y\in Y$ such that $|Y|\geq |G|$ and define $\rho:G\times Y\to X$ such that $\phi(\cdot,y_i)$ is bijective, namely the pair $(l,y)\in G\times Y$ is associated with exactly one $x_i$. As it hilds in general for group theory every field or group or abelian group is endowed with the operations of summation $\oplus_{G}$ ($\ominus_{G}$ resp. the subtraction) in $G$ and $\otimes_{G}$ in G. Can we prove the following?

If $l$ is a random variable with support on $G$ (since it takes vales on it) and $y$ is uniformly distributed over $G$ and independent of $l$, then the random variable defined as $x=l\ominus_{G}y$ is also uniformly distributed over $G$.

Comment: How are $X$, $Y$, $\rho$, and $\otimes_G$ related to your question? It seems to me that your actual question is formulated for random variables taking values in a finite group $G$.

Comment: @SangchulLee ``It seems to me that your actual question is formulated for random variables taking values in a finite group G" yes exactly. from cryptography $\rho$ is a cipher, where $y$ denotes the key to decrypt the message $l$ and $x$ is usually called an algorithm...in cryptography. However to avoid confusions I decided not to involve the jargon of cryptography in the problem just the mathematic formulation...

Comment: I only care about subtraction and summation... and not about $\otimes_{G}$. I just mentioned it as it is usually done. Maybe I shouldn't do it. So I can remove it from the text above to avoid further confusion, should I?

Comment: You don’t use anything about groups here, so it’s easier just to treat everything as sets. You also need $l$ to be uniform not just have full support.

Comment: The sets that the variables are defined are groups. Isn't that enough? Also why is it necessary to be uniform and not just have full support? I think the assumption is enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use multiplicative notation to allow $G$ to be non-abelian. Let

- $G$ be *any* finite group,
- $L$ be a random variable taking values in $G$,
- $Y$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed over $G$ and is independent of $L$.

Then $X=LY^{-1}$ is also uniformly distributed over $G$, since for each $g\in G$,

$$ \mathbf{P}(X=g)
= \mathbf{P}(Y=g^{-1}L)
= \sum_{l\in G}\mathbf{P}(Y = g^{-1}l)\mathbf{P}(L=l)
= \sum_{l\in G} \frac{1}{|G|}\mathbf{P}(L=l)
= \frac{1}{|G|}.$$

Comment: So, this holds for any non-abelian group whatever is the operation between $L$ and $Y$? so if the operation is subtraction or addition it works in the same way?

Comment: it seems to be ok to me...but could this also hold for abelian groups? what should we change in the proof?

Comment: @HungerLearn, Note that the proof works for *any* finite group. The multiplicative notation can be changed to additive notation if $G$ is abelian, but that is purely a notational matter, so nothing changes if you restrict yourself to finite abelian groups.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: for any finite abelian $G$ (with cardinality $p$), can I find a p-wise sequence of random vairables $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_p)$ that are uniformly distributed over $G$ such that y=$\sum_{i=1}^pa_i$ and the relation $x=l\ominus_G y=l\ominus_G \sum_{i=1}^pa_i$ still implies that $x$ is uniformly distributed over $G$?